# How to use a Unity like panel with Cinnamon desktop?

Tags: panel, cinnamon

I want to use a panel/dock (like Unity) in the left side of Cinnamon Desktop.

I tried using Plank, and pinned it to the left side of the screen, but there is no way to set it always on top.

How to create a Panel and set it always on top?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use DockbarX.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xuzhen666/dockbarx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dockbarx
```

You can pin apps into the DockbarX panel in the left side of the screen, just like that in Unity.

Also, add DockbarX to the list of startup applications.